# Computer coding of Perdew Burke and Ernzerhof (PBE) method

Tags: resource-recommendations, computational-physics, software, density-functional-theory

I have been assigned the task to write a computer code to implement the Perdew Burke and Ernzerhof ([PBE](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=perdew+burke+ernzerhof)) method. Does anyone know a good reference which can make the coding of this method easier?

Comment: Using a plane wave basis?

Comment: Yeah, I am trying to include the functions in this paper. http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.77.3865

Comment: And are you implementing it into some existing code? Or do you need to start from scratch?

Comment: To an existing code.

Comment: I found this website very resourceful for someone
interested in the PBE method. 
http://www.chem.uci.edu/~kieron/dftold/